# Creating an email with Powershell - I need date format corrected

Tags: powershell, rest, html-email

I am using `Invoke-RestMethod` to get data for an email about POs. It is working.

However, my arrival date column looks ugly:

```
ARR_Arrived_Date

10/16/2019 12:00:00 AM
10/10/2019 12:00:00 AM
10/9/2019 12:00:00 AM
10/8/2019 12:00:00 AM
```

I don't want the time, just the short date.

Here is the pertinent code:

```
$data = Invoke-RestMethod -Uri https://XXXXXXX/api/v1/BaqSvc/ArrivedPO/ -Credential $Cred -ContentType "Application/Json; charset=UTF-8"

$Header = @" <style> TABLE {border-width: 1px; border-style: solid;
border-color: #CCCCCC; border-collapse: collapse;} TH {border-width:
1px; padding: 3px; border-style: solid; border-color: black;
background-color: #00FF00;} TD {border-width: 1px; padding: 3px;
border-style: solid; border-color: black;} </style> "@

$message.IsBodyHTML = $true 

$message.Body = $data.value |
    ConvertTo-Html -Property ARR_PONum,ARR_PackSlip,ARR_Vendor_Name,ARR_Arrived_Date,ARR_Days_Arrived,ARR_FirstName,ARR_LastName,ARR_OrderNum,ARR_OpportunityID,ARR_Name -Head $Header
```

I don't know how to address ARR_Arrived_Date column for date formatting.
Please help!

Comment: you will likely need to feed `$Message.Body` to `Select-Object` so that you can use a calculated property to convert the date-time to just date.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [Calculated Properties](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/select-object?view=powershell-6), with [DateTime.ParseExact](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.datetime.parseexact?view=netframework-4.8), See an example:

```
$message.Body = $data.value |
ConvertTo-Html -Property ARR_PONum,ARR_PackSlip,ARR_Vendor_Name,
@{N="ARR_Arrived_Date";E={[DateTime]::ParseExact($_.ARR_Arrived_Date ,"MM/dd/yyyy hh:mm:ss tt",$null)}},
ARR_Days_Arrived,ARR_FirstName,ARR_LastName,ARR_OrderNum,
ARR_OpportunityID,ARR_Name -Head $Header
```

Comment: I tried this. While it did not error, my date column has nothing (except the header). Columns before and after have expected data displaying properly.

Comment: `@{N="Arrived_Date";E={$_.ARR_Arrived_Date.ToShortDateString()}}`     This is what worked!    Thanks for getting in the right direction!